# HttpURLConnection sends POST request twice

Tags: android

Using HttpURLConnection is the prefered way for http requests since Android 4.0.

**Problem**

When sending POST requests we had the effect, that the request was sent twice after an idle period of around 4 minutes.

The following snippet reproduces the problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    Button button = new Button( this );
    button.setText( "Perform POST request" );
    button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick( View v ) {

        new Thread( new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            makePostRequest();
          }

        } ).start();
      }
    } );
    setContentView( button );
  }

  private void makePostRequest() {
    try {
      String target = "http://server.com/path";
      System.out.println( "Sending POST request: " + target );
      URL url = new URL( target );
      HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
      conn.setDoOutput( true );
      System.out.println( "Response: " + conn.getResponseCode() );
    } catch( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

To reproduce: Hit the button. Wait four minutes. Hit the button again. The POST request of the second button hit is send to the server twice.

The issue only seems to arise on Android 4.1 and upwards. Couldn't reproduce it on 4.0.

**Solution**

The solve the issue we set the system property `http.keepAlive` to `false`. Thereby the POST request still sends the "Connection: keep-alive" header parameter but the HttpURLConnection does not attempt to resend a POST request after the 4 minutes idle period.

**Open Question**

Is that the expected behavior of the url connection on android? I would assume that POST requests are never retried. Having to configure it (via a system property) is very error prone.

Comment: But you do receive a response from your server the first time (which HttpURLConn can identify as such)?

Comment: The response is received the first time as expected. The second time the button is hit, the response from the second POST request is received.

Comment: can u try closing the connection using conn.disconnect()?

Comment: And have you tried to `disconnect()` after `conn.getResponseCode()`? It won't close the socket.

Comment: I guess the problem is due to excessive threads usage,use runnable instead of thread. It will solve the threading issue I think.

       new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  }
 };

Comment: read that runnables will suit connection/post/get than using threads, I may be wrong.

Comment: @LalithB Either you got that wrong, or the text you read used a misconception of the Thread and Runnable concepts, because Runnable and Thread objects do not compare and can't be exchanged for one another. Also, _not_ having a separate thread, directly or indirectly (via AsyncTask or so), for network communication in an Android app is close to impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. calling .disconnect() does not make a difference.